# Javascript to get start and end time based on radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, pre

I have an HTML code that looks like below.

```
<dd id="shifts">
<pre id="pre">
<input type="radio" name="shifts[]" id="shiftsValue" class="shiftsValue" onclick="shiftCheck();" value="185142249"> Shift No.1      Start time : 06:30:00 AM      End time : 10:30:00 AM<br>
</pre>
<pre id="pre"><input type="radio" name="shifts[]" id="shiftsValue" class="shiftsValue" onclick="shiftCheck();" value="185142250"> Shift No.2      Start time : 11:30:00 AM      End time : 15:30:00 PM<br>
</pre>
</dd>
```

This has worked fine and now there is a need to do time validation on `time` input type. I need to check the input for `time` such that the time entered is between the start and end time.

My thought is to get the string from the checked radio button and then extract the start and end time from the string. When the input is made into `time` element then check if it is between the start and end time.

I am having difficulty in extracting the string from above.

Comment: ideally you should try using some datepicker but if you are doing some custom function and have fixed values you can use date comparison in js

Comment: The HTML with time is an output from searching a list of shifts.  Any idea how I can extract "Shift No.1      Start time : xx:xx:xxAM      End time : xx:xx:xx AM"  from the two radio buttons when one of them is selected ?

Comment: I can get the text using this 
`document.getElementById('pre').innerText` . But this wont work if the second radio button is selected as this code only returns the first radio button's pre text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working

`$('input[type=radio][class=shiftsValue]:checked').closest('pre').text()`

seems to be getting the string for the `<pre>` of the selected radio button. Is this correct or should I try something else?